# Installing Ubuntu workstation and ubuntu server in a multi partition environment

Tags: system-installation

I've partitioned two 1TB drives into five partitions.

Vista went on disk 1 - partition 1 - Win 7 went onto disk 1 - partition 2 - Win server is going in on disk 2 - partition 1 - The remainder of disk 2 is split into two partitions named Ubuntu workstation and Ubuntu server.

I want to be able to tell Ubuntu to install in its dedicated partitions.

I'm installing the latest and greatest, V13 for both Ubuntu OS's.

I did read a post on here stating I should use "install alongside Windows".

Will that work for me?

I'm holding off installing any linux OS until I truly understand what I'm doing.

Also, Ubuntu Workstation is going in as the first linux OS, then server.
The following question is about the GRUB loader if it is still being used.

Once I've installed Ubuntu workstation, will the GRUB loader recognize all of my windows installs? If so, what about once I've installed Ubuntu server after workstation?

Thanks for everyone's help. I know this is a tricky configuration, but there is reason to my madness.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is something grub is very much designed for. By default, when grub gets control during boot, it offers you an interactive menu on your console screen that lets you select which OS you want to run.  You can configure grub to automatically run your preferred OS after a delay, or right away, for your convenience.

You might like to be aware that with two Linux systems (in this case Ubuntu systems) installed, you can expect to have a /boot/grub directory on each disk partition, and grub gets some files from there, in particular the menu.lst that controls the menu offered to you during boot.  Grub will always use the same /boot/grub directory once both Linux systems are both installed unless and until you ask for re-installation of grub itself, so it is not a big deal.

And yes, grub will recognize your windows installs and all of your Linux installs.